# PANDAS - Data carry forward until next data is available

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data stored in csv file . The columns include source, date , brand and multiple other columns that store data. The dates are not stored every month.
e.g.

| Brand | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 03-2018 | 54 |
| X | 03-2018 | 67 |
| ABC | 06-2018 | 22 |

what I want is to have all the months added in the date column and copy the data till next data for that brand is available.

Expected Output

| Brand | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 03-2018 | 54 |
| ABC | 04-2018 | 54 |
| ABC | 05-2018 | 54 |
| ABC | 06-2018 | 22 |
| X | 03-2018 | 67 |

same should happen for other brands.

What I have done so far is using two lists one contains the months present in data frame and another contains the range of months that I want my data to be carried forward. After comparing the lists the months not present in the list, the data for the previous month is saved in a new data frame. The issue here is that my loop is not iterating correctly and doing this for one month only.
Here is my code

```
for i in list_M:
    #print(type(i))
    for index, rows in df_hhp.iterrows():
        if(i in list_D):
        continue
        else:
          if(a<len(list_D)):
df_empty=df_empty.append(df_hhp.loc[df_hhp['Reported_Date']==list_D[a]])
            "Reported_Date"] = i
            a=a+1
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
df2 = df.groupby("Brand").agg({"Date":["min","max"]}).apply(
    lambda x: pd.date_range(x["Date","min"], x["Date","max"], freq='MS').strftime("%m-%Y").tolist(), axis=1).explode()
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df2.tolist(), columns=["Date"], index = df2.index)
pd.merge(df, df3, on=['Brand','Date'], how="outer").sort_values(["Brand", "Date"]).fillna(method='ffill').reset_index(drop=True)
```